# Running an external console app (that writes to the output file) from within web app controller

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, controller, console-application

I am running web app controller application (c#) on the server side. When particular http request comes in, the controller runs the external console application that reads the data input file and writes an output file with the result. The problem is that this external console app always outputs an empty file.
If I do this process manually by executing the external console app by myself (passing input and output files as parameters) it creates non empty output result file as expected.
Is that a security problem and is there any work around it?

My call to start the console app looks like this:

```
string a2tExePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), A2T_EXE);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append(" ").Append(Path.Combine(uploadFolder, A2T_INPUT)).Append(" ").Append(Path.Combine(uploadFolder, A2T_OUTPUT));
            using (System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process())
            {
                pProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
                pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = a2tExePath;// a2tExePath;
                pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = stringBuilder.ToString(); //argument
                
                pProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
                pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

                pProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                pProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; //not diplay a windows
                
                pProcess.Start();
                //string output = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); //The output result
                log.Info("Executing " + a2tExePath + " " + pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments);
                pProcess.WaitForExit();
            }

        }
```

Comment: How familiar are you with the a2tExe? If you have a dll you can bind to, consider using an extern call to Main https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern

Comment: Could you please give me a full example how I can call to Main function? I am not familiar with this technique.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're on Windows. This will run any one liner on a no-show command prompt:

```
public class Cmd
{
  public CommandLineResult Run(string singleLine)
  {
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    {
      Arguments = $"/c \"{singleLine}\"",
      UseShellExecute = false,
      CreateNoWindow = true,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      RedirectStandardError = true,
    };

    var process = Process.Start(startInfo);

    var stdErr = string.Empty;
    process!.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) => { stdErr += e.Data });
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    var stdOut = process?.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process?.WaitForExit();

    return new CommandLineResult
    {
      ExitCode = process?.ExitCode ?? -1,
      StandardOut = stdOut!,
      StandardErr = stdErr!,
    };
  }
}

public class CommandLineResult
{
  public int ExitCode { get; init; }
  public string StandardOut { get; init; } = null!;
  public string StandardErr { get; init; } = null!;
  public bool IsSuccess => ExitCode == 0;
  public string StandardAll = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, new[] { StandardOut, StandardErr });
}
```

You can use this like:

```
var inputPath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, A2T_INPUT);
var outputPath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, A2T_OUTPUT);
var singleLine = $"{a2tExePath} {inputPath} {outputPath}";
var result = new Cmd().Run(singleLine);
```

Alternatively, if you have a dll for a2t you can try extern binding to its Main function and call it directly (I think that's cleaner, if possible, since you're avoiding spinning up a new process as it's just a fancy function call). Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern

Comment: This c# code is similar to mine and does not create the output file - it is always empty. BTW you class does not compile -it has some errors with StandardOut and StandardErr not being static.

Comment: Can you please help me to fix the problem with the code you sent me. c# complains that the `StandardAll`  variable can't be initialized because `StandardOut StandardErr` are not static fields.